# Postgres upsert using results from select

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, upsert

I'm trying to upsert with postgres using values from a select. It looks like:

```
INSERT INTO foo (a, b, c)
SELECT a_, b_, c_
-- hairy sql
ON CONFLICT (...condition...) DO UPDATE
SET "c"=???
```

On conflict, I want to use one of the values from my select statement, but I can't find the right syntax to alias it. How can I do this with Postgres?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the `excluded` keyword:

```
INSERT INTO foo (a, b, c)
SELECT a_, b_, c_
-- hairy sql
ON CONFLICT (...condition...) DO UPDATE
  SET c = excluded.c;
```